# Maximum range for 8x8 bit multiplication

Tags: java

I am implementing a binary multiplication algorithm. Both inputs are signed decimal. They are each converted into 8-bit binary numbers and the final result is a 16-bit binary number.

I want to validate the input decimal number so that the product can safely fit as a 16-bit binary number and warn the user about overflow. How do I do that? I know I might only require a single IF statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Integer, decimal, or float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check that your two operands are both in the range `-128 .. 127` (i.e. valid 8 bit signed numbers).

If they are, then the result cannot possibly fall outside the range -16256 to +16384 - i.e. within the 16 bit signed range.

Comment: if(input1>=-128 && input1<=127) ?? then input1 is safe?

Answer (score 1):

A complement to Alnitak answer , to enable values greater than 127 (in case you dont use bytes) you can  compute the product in a temporary `long` variable  and then  check if this intermediary value can be represented by a short. Finally you cast to short .

Which gives something like:

```
long temp = input1*input2;
if (temp < -32768 || temp > 32767   ) 
   // signal error
   ...
else
   short value = (short)temp;
```

Comment: although an 8x8 bit multiplier won't take inputs outside that range anyway

Comment: @Alnitak I totally agree, but i wanted to comment on a general approach to overflows.

Comment: indeed, it's how I did overflow checks [for various math operators] on the 8-bit CPU emulator I wrote, and I did consider suggesting something similar, but I figured that doing a "real multiply" to check overflow was cheating when writing a binary multiplier from scratch ;-)